# Outgoing XML document has two xmlns attributes with different values after map

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces

A the title says, my XML document ends up with two xmlns attributes on the root node after executing my map, and is thus invalid according to XML syntax.

I am unsure what causes this behavior. The namespaces defined in my XSLT map are as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:s0="http://Dk.Customer/Name/Documents/VAT"
                xmlns:ns0="http://www.ape.us/abev/nyomtatvanyok/2004/02"
                xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp"
                xmlns:ScriptNS0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/ScriptNS0"
                xmlns:ScriptNS1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/ScriptNS1"
                xmlns:ScriptNS3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/ScriptNS3">
```

My root node in the outgoing XML:

```
<nyomtatvanyok    xmlns="http://www.ape.us/abev/nyomtatvanyok/2004/02"    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/ScriptNS3">
```

The target namespace in the output schema is http://www.ape.us/abev/nyomtatvanyok/2004/02.

The root node has the ns0 prefix:

```
<ns0:nyomtatvanyok>
```

Why is the second xmlns created in this case? What steps can I take to only keep the xmlns="http://www.ape.us/abev/nyomtatvanyok/2004/02" on the root node?

Comment: Please provide a (minimal) way to reproduce the problem. -- P.S. A namespace declaration is not an attribute.

Comment: An XSLT processor that outputs a document like this clearly has a bug. So the first thing we need to know is which XSLT processor you are using (including the product version); and then we need whatever it takes to reproduce the bug (typically a source document and stylesheet; possibly also the manner in which the transformation was effected.)

Comment: I notice that the second namespace has BizTalk in it as well as in the XSLT.  Is this a BizTalk map, if so add the BizTalk tag?  As others have said, you need to produce a reproducible example of the issue